# Change syslog log file's owner/group?

Tags: permissions, syslog, users, umask

Is there a way to have syslog create a log file that's not owned by root?

I've got several jboss application servers that I've got logging to a server. Everyone's running CentOS. Right now, all of the logs are going to 'somelog.log' and it's owned by root:root. Can I make that instead be another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible for you, migrate to syslog-ng. It allows you to specify file modes per-file basis and is much more granular in every way.